# How can I add a wxIcon to my frame app?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, icons

I've looked all over the net and can't seem to find a standard way of including a wxIcon in my wxWidgets app that actually works! I've tried converting the icon to an XPM and including that I've also tried loading the bitmap but whatever I do it seems to compile but the icon never appears!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying this on Windows make sure the icon is 32x32 pixels. All other sizes weren't being rendered at all...

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. But can anybody say what is the magig in size 32x32 on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the main icon for your application that you're talking about here? If so, you just need to have it as the first icon resource in your .rc file, e.g.:

```
mainicon ICON "myapp.ico"
```

If, on the other hand, you're setting an icon specifically on some other frame, then it should be enough to just set it via `wxTopLevelWindow::SetIcon`.

If neither of these works, perhaps you could post a sample of your code that isn't working?

Comment: thanks for the reply I'll give it a go when I get a chance - and its the icon for the main wxFrame which I'm trying to add the icon to.